# MySQL query to compare content of one column with title of other column

Tags: mysql

I know the title makes no sense at first glance. But here's the situation: the DB table is named 'teams'. In it, there are a bunch of columns for positions in a soccer team (gk1, def1, def2, ... , st2). Each column is type VARCHAR and contains a player's name. There is also a column named 'captain'. The content of that column (not the most fortunate solution) is not the name of the captain, but rather the position.

So if the content of 'st1' is Zlatan Ibrahimovic and he's the captain, then the content of 'captain' is the string 'st1', and not the string 'Zlatan Ibrahimovic'.

Now, I need to write a query which gets a row form the 'teams' table, but only if the captain is Zlatan Ibrahimovic. Note that at this point **I don't know if he plays st1, st2 or some other position.** So I need to use just the name in the query, to check if the position he plays on is set as captain. Logically, it would look like:

if(Zlatan is captain)
get row content

In MySQL, the if condition would actually be the 'where' clause. But is there a way to write it?

```
$query="select * from teams where ???";
```

The "Teams" table structure is:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   gk1   |   def1  |   def2  | ... |   st2   |     captain     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| player1 | player2 | player3 | ... | playerN | captainPosition |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Whith all fields being of VARCHAR type.

Answer (score 2):

Because the content of the `captain` column is the position and not the name, and you want to choose based on the position, this is trivial.

```
$query="select * from teams where captain='st1'";
```

---

**Revised following question edit:**

Your database design doesn't allow this to be done very efficiently. You are looking at a  query like

```
 SELECT * FROM teams WHERE
    (gk1='Zlatan' AND captain='gk1') OR
    (de1='Zlatan' AND captain='de1') OR
    ...
```

The design mandates this sort of query for many functions: how you can find the team which a particular player plays for without searching every position? [Actually you could do *that* by finding the name in a concatenation of all the positions, but it's still not very efficient or flexible]

A better solution would be to normalise your data so you had a single table showing which player was playing where:

```
 Situation
 Team | Player | Posn | Capt
 -----+--------+------+------
    1 |     12 |    1 |    0
    1 |     11 |    2 |    1
    1 |     13 |   10 |    0
```

...with other tables which allow you to identify the Team, Player and Postion referenced here. There would need to be some referential checks to ensure that each team had only one captain, and only plays one goalkeeper, etc.

You could then easily see that the captain of Team 1 is Player 11 who plays in position 2; or find the team (if any) for which player 11 is captain.

```
SELECT Name FROM Teams
WHERE Situation.Team = Teams.id
  AND Situation.Capt = 1
  AND Situation.Player = Players.id
  AND Players.Name = 'Zlatan';
```

A refinement on that idea might be

```
 Situation
 Team | Player | Posn | Capt | Playing
 -----+--------+------+------+--------
    1 |     12 |    1 |    0 |       1
    1 |     11 |    2 |    1 |       1
    1 |     13 |   10 |    0 |       0
    1 |     78 |    1 |    0 |       0
```

...so that you could have two players who are goalkeepers (for example) but only field of them.

Redesigning the database may be a lot of work; but it's nowhere near as complicated or troublesome as using your existing design. And you will find that the performance is better if you don't need to use inefficient queries.

Comment: My question was poorly formulated, please check my edit (in bold letters) and my comment to the other answer above.

Comment: @robert Answer updated. It is a form of the stereotypical "If you want to go there, I wouldn't start from here," though.

Answer (score 0):

By what have you exposed, you just need to put the two conditions and check if the query returned 1 record. If it returns no records, he is not the captain:

```
SELECT *
FROM Teams
WHERE name = 'Zlatan Ibrahimovic' AND position = 'st1';
```

Comment: There is no 'position' column OR 'name' column, and also I don't know which of the 18 positions on the team he plays, so your answer makes zero sense.

Comment: I think you are not exposing exactly what you think. Or all here are dumb or you are wrong.

Comment: Sure, why don't you just solve the problem by using columns that don't exist in your query.

Comment: How can I know the columns if you dont post the table sctructure. Can you?

Comment: The best think you could do is to change this structure. If not, your only hope is to use 2 queries to get what you want. It's not possible to use a column value to get a column name in pure SQL with jst one query.

Comment: See, that's actually the answer I was looking for. Thank you.